# Log in function in monorail c#

Tags: castle-monorail

Could anyone give me any good link to log in function in monorail c#?

I am a newbie to monorail c# and need to implement one log in function.

Thank you.

Mealea

Answer (score 1):

[Here's one from Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/03/03/CastleDemoAppViewComponentsSecurityFiltersAndFriends.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Like in Ayende's solution, the best way is to just use the ASP.net authentication mechanisms.  Here's an example action on a LoginController:

```
        [AccessibleThrough(Verb.Post)]
    public void Authenticate(string username, string password, bool autoLogin, string returlUrl)
    {
        SomeWebServiceAuthenticationProvider wsSecurity = new SomeWebServiceAuthenticationProvider();


        bool isValid = wsSecurity.ValidateUser(username, password);

        if (isValid)
        {
            //first perform a logout to make sure all other cookies are cleared
            InternalLogout();

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, autoLogin);
            PropertyBag["username"] = username;
            PropertyBag["password"] = password;
            PropertyBag["autoLogin"] = autoLogin;

            //redirect back to the Home page, or some other page
            if (!RedirectToPreviousUrl()) Redirect("home", "index");
        }
        else
        {
            Flash["auth_error"] = "Invalid user name or password.";
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

You can substitute some other authentication mechanism in place of 'SomeWebServiceAuthenticationProvider"... the point here is that we're just calling the standard FormsAuthentication methods.

Comment: Mealea, can you choose an answer? This question has been sitting around for a while.